# How to log commands issued from Intellij with Scala plugin to SBT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I worked some time with SBT and a text editor. Then, moved to Intellij, installed [Scala plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=1347), and created a new project as in the [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnQbJ.png) by choosing it to be based on SBT. Also, in the settings, I chose the SBT launcher to be custom, and made it point to the already-installed sbt.

I believe Intellij is probably calling SBT commands like `sbt run` and stuff in the background. My question: **How can I see (a log of) these commands as they're called by Intellij to sbt and their responses?** And as a plus: where can I edit them? I opened the "Edit Configurations" but couldn't find anything like `sbt compile`.

I believe Intellij shows the responses (e.g., [info] downloading...) below in the "Background Tasks", but

**1. It doesn't log these responses and**

**2. It doesn't show the commands issued by Intellij to sbt.**

Big picture/what I'd really want to do: have the IntelliSense features from Intellij and Scala plugin, but build and run from the terminal and not have any effects from Intellij on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IntelliJ Scala plugin doesn't (yet) call sbt except for project import/refresh or if you have a run configuration that uses sbt. Compilation is done by the built-in compile server. If you prefer to use IntelliJ as an editor and run tasks from the sbt console, that usually works fine.

Comment: What command does it call sbt with on project import/refresh, or where can I see them?

Comment: It runs a custom task in a separate sbt process. There is no direct output for that, but warnings and errors end up in the Event Log

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question well
do u want to see the SBT output? if you are using run/debug you will see both the command & the output in the **run window** (alt+4)
also intelliJ has a window called **event log**

I hope that help

Comment: More like wanting to see the SBT output. Specifically:  
- Probably, Intellij called `sbt compile` and other calls. I want to see these calls.  
- See SBT's output.  
  
Alt+4 is nice, didn't notice the command above. However, this doesn't have any calls to sbt. Does this mean Intellij doesn't even use it?  
  
And Event log doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij reads the projects configuration from sbt and creates an equivalent configurations for its project format (either .idea folder or .ipr)

this is a similar question to yours but about maven, you may find helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167052/2675679