# Using openCSV in Java on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, opencsv

I am so frustrated right now. I was trying to follow this tutorial
https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/ to use openCSV in java to read some file. After I set up every thing. I got these error.  [image: I got some error like this]

[image: I got some error like this]

And, then I did some research. And I follow the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42929382/8371801

Now my pom look like this [image]

Then the problem fixed. Every thing works perfect. So I just want to know what happened. What does pom file exactly do? What does Maven exactly do? I did many researches on line but I am still so confused. Why my java version is 10.1 it still work when I enter 1.8 in pom.

Comment: Please, NO CODE IMAGES.  Copy/paste all relevant text from your IDE and include it as TEXT (code-formatted where appropriate).  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  Also, before asking "What does POM do", please do some research to understand what Maven is and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maven does many things. In your case it downloads the opencsv library for you and invokes `javac` for you.

The properties you've set in your pom.xml (one of maven's configuration files) control whats passed in `javac`'s `-source` and `-target` options.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially thru maven you have defined what version of java to use. You can also do the same kind of thing going to the modules->dependencies in the module settings.

A useful link 
[Difference between intellij Project make and Maven Compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166698/difference-between-intellij-project-make-and-maven-compile)